# How to write grammar for token of a string except a certain word in javacc

Tags: javacc

i have a token for String such as :

```
   Token:{
      <STING: (["0"-"9"]
["a"-"z"]
["A"-"Z"])+>
    }
```

and i want to except a certain word such as "word" , how to write token for
 that in javcc?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclude a string as a token in Javacc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320116/exclude-a-string-as-a-token-in-javacc)

Comment: Good question, but it's been answered many times before, including in the FAQ.